# ArrayList empty

Tags: java, arraylist

I think it's a simple question but keeps me from moving forward in the project. Why, when I use the `ArrayList` as a reference from a class to another, it is empty?

```java
public class FirstClass {
    private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<String> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
        fc.getMyList().add("Test");
        System.out.println(fc.getMyList());
    }
}
```

Output when I run `FirstClass.main`:

```
[Test]
```

---

```java
public class OtherClass {
    FirstClass csv = new FirstClass();
    public ArrayList<String> otherList = csv.getMyList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
        System.out.println(oc.otherList);
    }
}
```

Output when running the `OtherClass.main`:

```
[]
```

I've Googled so many time and the solutions that I found are not working. I followed step by step, creating a *getter* method in the class that is populating the `ArrayList`, use the method to populate it, use the `print` method to make sure the array is populated at the end of the `main` method. All good, `ArrayList` is full and ready to be used but when used as reference is empty.

Comment: Wait, when you never add an item to the list it won't contain any items? That weird, isn't it? Have you tried to add items instead?

Comment: fc.getMyList().add("Test"); this is not adding to the list ?

Comment: It would when you would call that main method, but you don't. You call that other main method in the OtherClass instead.

Comment: I've also tried:  fc.myList.add("Test"); still not printing anything in the 2nd class

Comment: So how my code should look to work?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
        System.out.println(fc.getMyList());

    } still printing empty array

Comment: But think about the flow of execution. Why would there be anything in that list? Nothing is executed during the instantiation of `FirstClass` that would add to its list.

Comment: I wonder why you keep adding main methods which just do one thing and not everything you want it to do. You want it do add stuff to a list and then print it, like you did in your first example, so do the same in your second one. Spread different steps to different main methods which have no relation doesn't work, they don't interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Because a new instance of `FirstClass` is being created inside of `OtherClass`, `otherList` in `OtherClass` is empty.

The ArrayList that `oc.otherList` refers to is different from the one that you populated for `FirstClass` in the main method.

You can edit your `OtherClass` to work:

```
public class OtherClass {
   private FirstClass csv;
   public ArrayList<String> otherList;

   public OtherClass(FirstClass fc) {
       this.csv = fc;
       this.otherList = fc.getMyList();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
       fc.getMyList().add("Test");
       OtherClass oc = new OtherClass(fc);
       System.out.println(oc.otherList);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OtherClass creates the FirstClass without FirstClass main method, so it does not add() to the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like below.

```java
public class FirstClass {

    private List<String> myList;

    // Instance block: will executed the moment you create object
    // of FirstClass
    {
        myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add("Test String");
    }

    public List<String> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

```java
public class OtherClass {

    private static List<String> otherList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
        otherList = fc.getMyList();
        System.out.println(otherList); //iterate if want to check specific elements in the list
    }
}
```

Or a better way would be to create a method which will add elements to the list and read it in the otherclass by calling the method using firstclass's object.